# To find nullity of a surjective linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:U \to V$ be a surjective linear mapping and $dim(U)=6$,$dim(V)=3$.Then

a) $dim(ker$ $T)$ is greater than $4 $

b) $dim(ker$ $T)$$ = 4 $

c) $dim(ker$ $T)$ is greater than $3 $

d) $dim(ker$ $T)$$ = 3 $

> $dim(U)= dim(ker $ T)$ $+$dim(Im $ T)
>
> $6=dim(ker $ T)+$dim(Im $ T)
>
> Now how to solve ...?Is it possible to say $dim(Im $ T) will be less than $3$ ?

Comment: Hint: It is assumed that $T$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T$ is surjective then $\dim Im(T)=\dim V=3$. Now use the rank-nullity theorem
$$\dim U=\dim Im(T)+\dim\ker(T)$$